# Anyone who knows a way around the error on Android Lifecycle plugin error on flutter

Tags: flutter

\flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.8-stable\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-1.0.6\android\src\main\kotlin\io\flutter\plugins\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle\FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin.kt. This is likely to due to an incorrect `androidPackage: io.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle` or `mainClass` entry in the plugin's pubspec.

I keep on getting this error when installing the google map flutter plugin and the image picker